# Constructive proof of the disjunctive syllogism in Natural Deduction for Intuitionistic Logic

Tags: proof-verification, constructive-mathematics, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

Is my constructive proof of the disjunctive syllogism principle correct?

[image]

Comment: I think not. I think you must start with the assumption $(\phi\lor Q)\land\lnot\phi$, prove $Q$, and then using ($\rightarrow I$) prove the last formula.

Comment: The principle of disjunctive syllogism governs just disjunction and negation, not also conjunction and conditional.  It is cleaner to seek an intuitionistic proof of $\Phi\lor Q, \neg \Phi\vdash Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mohsen Shahriari, your derivation is not correct: to obtain a correct derivation you should explicit the rules used in the "vertical dots" part of your derivation.

The following is a derivation of $((\Phi \lor Q) \land \lnot \Phi) \to Q$ in intuitionistic (and hence "constructive") natural deduction.
[image: derivation in intuitionistic natural deduction]

where efq is the rule *ex falso quodlibet*, also known as $\bot_E$, which is a rule of intuitionistic (and then classical) natural deduction but it not admissible in minimal natural deduction.